# Moving a ball around the screen in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I wanted to move the ellipse around the screen using if statement I only made it move left and down and right but I couldn't manage to move it up so it complete a full cycle that is my code:

```js
var x;
var y;
var r=33;
var speed=4;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(660, 500);
    x=width;
    y=0;
}

function draw() {
    background("black");
    ellipse(x,y,r)

    if(x<=width&&x>=0)
    {
      if(y<=0)
          x-=12;
      else if(y>=height)
          x+=21;

    }
    if(y>=0&&y<=height)
    {
        if(x>=width)
          y-=21;
        else if(x<=0)
          y+=21
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, that the ball does not stop exactly at the borders of the window. It slightly moves beyond. Use [`min()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/min) and [`max()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/max), to keep the ball in bounds.

e.g.:

```js
x = max(r, x - speed_x);
```

```js
y = min(height-r, y + speed_y);
```

See the example

```js
var x, y, r=25, speed_x = 12, speed_y = 12;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 200);
    x=width-r;
    y=r;
}

function draw() {
    background("black");
    ellipse(x,y, r*2)

    // move left
    if (y == r && x > r)
        x = max(r, x - speed_x);

    // move down
    if (x == r && y < height-r)
        y = min(height-r, y + speed_y);

    // move right
    if (y == height-r && x < width-r)
        x = min(width-r, x + speed_x);

    // move up
    if (x == width-r && y > r)
        y = max(r, y - speed_y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
```